# concrete ceiling anchor: how much weight can it support?

Tags: ceiling, anchor

Not sure if ceiling anchor is the correct term, so I attached a picture for reference.

I removed the drop ceiling from my basement, the metal frame holding the tiles were screwed into these wholes (anchors?), so I have quite a few across my concrete ceiling (roughly 1-1.5 meters apart from each other).

My question is, how much weight can these anchors support? They are about 2 cm deep and 9 mm wide. I am thinking of installing a hammock / pull up bar / perhaps use it to support a small bouldering wall if possible.

Any answer is highly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: As a test you could screw in a bolt and see if you could rip a sample anchor out with a crowbar. That would give you a very rough idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be very difficult to say without knowing the exact company and part number. I found reference to something that **might** be similar here:

https://www.ccinetwork.com/p-39-38-sanko-shorty-drop-in-anchor-box-of-100.aspx

The info sheet says 2,200 to 5,500 pounds, but again, **I wouldn't mount anything expensive or dangerous in them without a lot of stress testing**. It would probably be worth bringing in a contractor to take a look and give you some kind of idea.

Drop ceilings don't weigh that much and it sounds like the weight was distributed over a lot of these anchors so that would suggest to me that they are not designed for heavy loads.

Comment: Thank you, that would be my guess as well. I don't think too much was invested into these anchors so as you suggest, I'll go with "probably not enough to hold something heavy", specially a moving object